# Binding results of an linq to xml query to the same gridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, linq-to-xml

How can I bind the results of my linq to xml query parser to the same gridview. I'm only able to see the last one for the ZAxisCalib/query3.

```
 string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Sciclone UAC", "*.cfg*");
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
            var query = from x in doc.Descendants("XAxisCalib")
                        select new
                        {

                            MaxChild = x.Descendants("Max"),
                            MinChild = x.Descendants("Min")
                        };
            {
                var bs1 = new BindingSource { DataSource = query };

                dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                dataGridView1.AutoSize = true;

                dataGridView1.DataSource = bs1;
            }


            var query2 = from y in doc.Descendants("YAxisCalib")

                         select new
                         {

                             MaxChild = y.Descendants("Max"),
                             MinChild = y.Descendants("Min")

                         };


            var bs2 = new BindingSource { DataSource = query2 };

            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGridView1.AutoSize = true;

            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs2;


            var query3 = from z in doc.Descendants("ZAxisCalib")

                         select new
                         {

                             MaxChild = z.Descendants("Max"),
                             MinChild = z.Descendants("Min")
                         };

            var bs3 = new BindingSource { DataSource = query3 };

            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGridView1.AutoSize = true;

            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs3;

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're *replacing* the datasource each time. If you just want to concatenate the results of the three queries, you could use:

```
var source = new BindingSource { DataSouce = query1.Concat(query2)
                                                   .Concat(query3) };
dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
```

Comment: Thanks yes that worked. But only problem is that my code is only doing this for one file in the folder do you see anything wrong with my code where its opening the directory that contains the files to be parsed. I need it to parse all file sin teh folder but is only doing it for one.

Comment: @Casey: No, it's doing it for all of them - but replacing the results on each iteration...

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Sciclone UAC", "*.cfg*");
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
            var query = from x in doc.Descendants("XAxisCalib")
                        select new
                        {

                            MaxChild = x.Descendants("Max"),
                            MinChild = x.Descendants("Min")
                        };
          /*  {
                var bs1 = new BindingSource { DataSource = query };

                dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                dataGridView1.AutoSize = true;

                dataGridView1.DataSource = bs1;
            }*/


            var query2 = from y in doc.Descendants("YAxisCalib")

                         select new
                         {

                             MaxChild = y.Descendants("Max"),
                             MinChild = y.Descendants("Min")

                         };


          /*  var bs2 = new BindingSource { DataSource = query2 };

            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGridView1.AutoSize = true;

            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs2;*/


            var query3 = from z in doc.Descendants("ZAxisCalib")

                         select new
                         {

                             MaxChild = z.Descendants("Max"),
                             MinChild = z.Descendants("Min")
                         };

            var bs3 = new BindingSource { DataSource = query.Union(query2.Union(query3)) };

            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGridView1.AutoSize = true;

            dataGridView1.DataSource =bs3;

        }
```

I don't compile it, it is a fast sketch

Comment: Thanks yes that worked. But only problem is that my code is only do it for one file in the folder do you see anything wrong with my code where its opening the directory that contains the files to be parsed.