# When doing linq to xml and displaying data in datagridview my code only parses one file in directory folder

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview, linq-to-xml

How come during the linq to xml parse my code is only reading one fo the xml files in the folder rather than all of them?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"", "*.cfg*");
    foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
        var query = from x in doc.Descendants("")
                    select new
                    {

                        MaxChild = x.Element("Max").Value,
                        MinChild = x.Element("Min").Value
                    };


        var query2 = from y in doc.Descendants("")

                     select new
                     {

                         MaxChild = y.Element("Max").Value,
                         MinChild = y.Element("Min").Value

                     };


        var query3 = from z in doc.Descendants("")

                     select new
                     {

                         MaxChild = z.Element("Max").Value,
                         MinChild = z.Element("Min").Value
                     };

        var bs3 = new BindingSource { DataSource = query.Union(query2.Union(query3)) };

        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataGridView1.AutoSize = true;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs3;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Max";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Min";

    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're iterating over the files in the directory - but simply reassigning the datasource each time. In other words, it's exactly the same problem as in your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405442/binding-results-of-an-linq-to-xml-query-to-the-same-gridview), except that instead of it being to do with three queries, it's to do with reassigning it for each file.

Try this instead, using a single query:

```
var query = from file in fileEntries
            let doc = XDocument.Load(file)
            from x in doc.Descendants("XAxisCalib")
                         .Concat(doc.Descendants("YAxisCalib"))
                         .Concat(doc.Descendants("ZAxisCalib"))
            select new
            {
                // Include this to see the file for each value
                File = file,
                MaxChild = x.Element("Max").Value,
                MinChild = x.Element("Min").Value
            };

var bs3 = new BindingSource { DataSource = query };

dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dataGridView1.AutoSize = true;

dataGridView1.DataSource = bs3;
```

EDIT: Okay, if you know there's going to be exactly one of each element, it's fairly easy:

```
var query = from file in fileEntries
            let doc = XDocument.Load(file)
            let x = doc.Descendants("XAxisCalib").Single()
            let y = doc.Descendants("YAxisCalib").Single()
            let z = doc.Descendants("ZAxisCalib").Single()
            select new
            {
                // Include this to see the file for each value
                File = file,
                MaxChildX = x.Element("Max").Value,
                MinChildX = x.Element("Min").Value,
                MaxChildY = y.Element("Max").Value,
                MinChildY = y.Element("Min").Value,
                MaxChildZ = z.Element("Max").Value,
                MinChildZ = z.Element("Min").Value
            };
```

Comment: No that didn't work that creates the same datagridview but I applaud your shorter way of writing my linq to xml query. It only did it for one xml file in the folder again.

Comment: Is there a way for it to iterate each of the files and put all values in the same datagridview thats what I would like it to do?

Comment: @Casey: That query really *should* do it for all the files... truly. What happens if you log `query.Count()` before binding it? What about `fileEntries.Length`?

Comment: Oops my fault your code was right I just deleted too much of my code and all that minor error but I got it. Thank You!!!

Comment: I have one more question as you seem to  know datagridview somewhat well. Do you know if I can add the data to the datagridview all to the same row cause right now its adding to two columns  max and min

Comment: @Casey: I don't know DataGridView at all, but I know LINQ. It's unclear to me why you'd *want* everything all on the same row - you've selected several elements, all with max and min elements. The whole point of a data *grid* is that it's a grid, not just a list of one column.

Comment: Well I would like one file to be all on one row then the next on the next row and so on but I will post a new question and see if anyone knows.

Comment: @Casey: Ah, each file on one row... um, that's still not terribly easy, but you could have another column with the filename in if that would help - I can add that now.

Comment: That might help. I will try it and see.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3414/discussion-between-casey-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: @Casey: No, I'm doing umpteen other things at the same time - I can't do chat. Please continue in comments, I'm afraid.

Comment: haha ok no problem sorry. What I was thinking was would breaking it back into three different queries work but when it calls for 'select new' of each name them differently ie; max 1, max 2, max 3, min1, min2, min3.

Comment: would that help to break them up into 6 different columns? if we just name them differently so that their not all going under column max and column min.

ps- file = file worked thanks it even imported to excel with it.(Thats what i'm doing ultimately with the datagridview is its getting transferred to excel spreadsheet thats why is all one file was in one row would look better)

Comment: @Casey: Um, it's slightly tricky - because it's not like we can guarantee that there's one XAxisCalib per YAxisCalib etc... unless that *is* the file format. If you could show what the XML looks like, that could help.

Comment: I will paste it in my first original question post above.

Comment: See above. yes that is the file format it declares x/y/z calib and their only one max and min per file.

Comment: Wow Jon Thanks so much. I already had th excel part so the linq xml query was what I needed adn you helped so much. It looks awesome and works perfectly. Thank You!!!